# AngularJS Clicking on Add button should display a new popup page by hiding the parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on a project which uses AngularJS/Breeze framework using HotTowel Template.

I have a requirement where, in a parent.html page I have a button/link as "Add" and on click of this button, I need to display a popup page by hiding the parent page(i.e.parent.html).

Add page will have input controls and Save button where user will enter the details in the respective control and on click of Save button data from input controls will be saved to the database table.

I am new to this AngularJS style coding, please advise me or provide me a link on how I should implement the display a child popup page by hiding the parent page(i.e.parent.html) as explained above.

Comment: can you give us some code

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question is that you need to use modals.

You can try using [angular ui modals](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

This creates a pop up by fading the primary page. You can create input controls and save buttons in the modal